# How to make terminal minimal Vs Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am trying to make terminal interference minimal by removing element I don't need. I am beginner in programming.

I want to remove the highlighted part.:
[image]

I am using [coderunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) and [C/C++ Compile Run](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danielpinto8zz6.c-cpp-compile-run). I lloked for this on google and but Code-runner: Clear previous output, it does not work for me. Also is there any way I can clear terminal automatically when running the code using ctrl+alt+N instead doing it manually?
If I can't do this in powershell is there any other shell which give this functionality?

Comment: Can you show us the executor macro currently configured for `C/C++`? Open settings and search for `code-runner.executorMap`

Comment: i don't see any hilite in the text image you posted. what are you talking about?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I meant the whole grey part. Ps: >cd.....

Comment: ah! take a look at `Get-Help Clear-Host`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Can I automate Clear-Host or clear whenever I want to run code instead of typing it everytime I run code in terminal?  Like by adding something in code.

Comment: @NewOzaiSocietyMember - you can call the cmdlet whenever you want. [*grin*] one commonly calls it just before a call to `Read-Host`, but you can use it at any time.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I am using system("CLS") on top in my int main(). It is working good. Thanks.

Comment: @NewOzaiSocietyMember - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]